# createAsyncThunk - changing the state on pending doesn't cause immediate rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm using typescript, useSelector and @reduxjs/toolkit...

...When I dispatch the **computeConfidenceIntervalsAsync** action (see the code below), I can see the code running the following line immediatly:
`state.status = 'loading'`

But the **ViewComponent** is re-rendered only after the payloadCreator has finished running the **doSomeHeavyComputation** function.

To explain it in another way: in the ViewComponent I would expect the 'loading' state rendered before the heavy computation but for some reason the heavy computation is run first, then I receive 'loading' and 'idle' in a row.

Any help on this one?

Reducer:

```js
//...

export const computeConfidenceIntervalsAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'forecast/getConfidenceIntervals',
  async (data: ConfidenceIntervalsParams) => {
    const response = await getConfidenceIntervals(data.totalRuns, data.itemsTarget, data.throughputs, new Date(data.startingDate));
    return [...response.entries()];
  }
);

export const forecastSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'forecast',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(computeConfidenceIntervalsAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(computeConfidenceIntervalsAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.confidenceIntervals = action.payload;
      });
  }
});

export const selectForecast = (state: RootState) => state.forecast;
//...
```

service:

```js
//...
export function getConfidenceIntervals(totalRuns: number, itemsTarget: number, throughputs: number[], startingDate: Date) {
  return new Promise<Map<string, number>>((resolve) => {
    console.log('beginning');
    const outcomes = doSomeHeavyComputation(totalRuns, itemsTarget, throughputs, startingDate);
    console.log('ending');
    resolve(outcomes);
  });
}
//...
```

Component:

```js
export function ViewComponent() {
  const forecast = useAppSelector(selectForecast);
  console.log(forecast)

  if (forecast.status === 'loading') {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }

  return (<div>...</div>);
```

useSelector hook

```js
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../redux';

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous work is blocking - and not really what `cAT` is designed for.
You can make this work by doing something like

```js
export async function getConfidenceIntervals(totalRuns: number, itemsTarget: number, throughputs: number[], startingDate: Date) {
    await Promise.resolve() // this will defer this to the next tick, allowing React to render in-between
    console.log('beginning');
    const outcomes = doSomeHeavyComputation(totalRuns, itemsTarget, throughputs, startingDate);
    console.log('ending');
    return outcomes;
}
```

(I've taken the liberty of rewriting it to async/await)

Your promise would have started immediately with no pause in-before so I added an `await Promise.resolve()` which defers execution by a tick.

Comment: Thank you! I think your solution has fixed part of the issue: now I'm able to run this code in the ViewComponent right before the heavy synchronous work starts: `if (forecast.status === 'loading') {...}` However for some reason the loading element (<div>Loading...</div>) is not rendered in the browser yet.

Comment: React itself may use time slicing, splitting it's work into multiple pieces that run your code in-between. You might need to set some timeout before starting your work. Generally though you should avoid running expensive work on the main thread or add lots of `await Promise.resolve()` to allow other code running in-between. Otherwise, your browser will seem frozen.

Comment: setTimeout worked fine, but, as you suggested, I ended up using web workers for the expensive job (no need for the `await Promise` bit anymore). Thanks again.